# Is the Kansas flavor of Solitaire winnable

Tags: solitaire

So I have recently started playing a variant of solitaire called "Kansas"

https://politaire.com/help/kansas

and either I'm really bad at it (have lost dozens of times over past month) or it might just be very unlikely for a person to win the game.  I was curious to if anyone had experience with it or any references to why it might be "unwinnable"

Comment: The online interface makes it much more difficult than the actual game. It automatically moves cards to the foundation instead of letting you use them in the tableau.

Comment: I looked at the rules and it didn't mention this, probably one of the reasons I took so long

thanks for responding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won 1 out of 9 games.  (I stopped with my first win.)

Note, that @LScottJohnson's comment is not quite true.  You can "undo" a card moving up to the foundation.  That was a necessary feature for the win that I got.

If you find Kansas very annoyingly difficult to win (I do), the website does offer the nearly identical game [Rainbow](https://politaire.com/help/rainbow) which is easier to win.

Comment: That is what I figured out as well - just won my first game a few minutes ago.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I normally treat take-backs (undo) as cheating in solitaire. It's not a paradigm I'd give up for the "pleasure" of playing this, I think. :)